# Add a years field to a date field?

Tags: business-intelligence, sap

I have the below fields and would like to add the contract_term field to the date field:

Contract_Term: Years
Date: YYYY/MM/DD

For example: 3(contract_term) + 2019/01/01(date) = 2022/01/01

What would be the best way for me to achieve the above result?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you could use [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) pretty easily.

```
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, 3, '2019-01-01') AS math
```

Just substitute in the columns in your table, something like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, contract_term, contract_date) AS math
FROM dbo.your_table;
```